# Python 2.7 and pip from 3.5

Tags: package-management, python, python-2.7

I do not know what has happened because this used to work fine but I'm now experiencing a problem where I am running python2.7 but for some reason pip is installing in my python 3.5 dist-packages.

At least, I think this is the case based on when I type `python -V` I get `Python 2.7.10` and when I type `pip -V` I get `pip 8.1.2 from /usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages (python 3.5)`

This is causing me knock on problems when setting up `virtualenv` etc.  I've tried uninstalling and installing pip but it is still going back to 3.5.  Could I have some advice please.

Comment: Which one of `python-pip` and `python3-pip` (or both) do you have installed?

Comment: I've only deliberately installed python-pip using `sudo apt-get install pip` but I've just checked and I have the latest versions of both installed

Comment: So I've just run `sudo apt-get remove python3-pip` but when I try `pip -V` I get the same directory still

Comment: I've now completely removed python3.5 and when I try `pip -V` I get `-bash: /usr/local/bin/pip: /usr/bin/python3.5: bad interpreter: No such file or directory` but if I try to install pip I'm messaged it is already there.  Obviously a path issue, but how do I change it?

Comment: @HenryM `sudo apt-get install pip` in fact wouldn't work because there is no package named `pip` in the Ubuntu repositories. You probably meant `sudo apt-get install python-pip` (for Python 2) or `sudo apt-get install python3-pip` (for Python 3). Regardless, do you recall ever upgrading `pip`? If so, how did you upgrade `pip`?

Answer (score 3):

If `python2` and `python3` are both installed, and `pip` for both has been installed,  then there should be a separate `pip2` and `pip3` command that you can use, for the corresponding version of python.

Note: you have to explicitly install both pip versions:  `apt-get install python-pip` for python2, and `apt-get install python3-pip` for python3.

Alternatively (but still requiring `apt-get install` of `pip`), you can use the `pip` module from your `python` executable directly, if you have Python 2.7.9 and later (on the python2 series), or Python 3.4+.

For example, on Ubuntu 16.04, after installing/upgrading python2 and python3 and both pip versions:

```
$ pip --version 
pip 8.1.1 from /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages (python 2.7)

$ pip3 --version 
pip 8.1.1 from /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages (python 3.5)

$ python2 -m pip --version 
pip 8.1.1 from /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages (python 2.7)

$ python3 -m pip --version 
pip 8.1.1 from /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages (python 3.5)
```